# Validate a value of a watching variable and prevent assignments if it not fit requirements without firing the watch function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a jsBin snippet http://jsbin.com/aKEXOva/3

The idea is watch for a variable's value, and when it fails the validation, return its previous value without firing a watch function again.

I thinking of the scenario

1. if validation failed run unwatch() listener
2. assign its previous value
3. watch it again

.... but kinda hope there is a better way to do that.
Is AngularJs providing built-in mechanism?

I will appreciate any help or clues.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why just not use ng-change in your input?

```
<input ng-model="value" ng-change="change()"/>

//in your controller
$scope.value = "";
var old = $scope.value;
$scope.change() {
  if (isValid($scope.value)) {
     old = $scope.value;
  } else {
     $scope.value = old;
  }
}
```

Actually using a watchers is a bad bad thing...